# Pattern matching in database

Tags: database, text, design-patterns, matching

I want to search every rows of specific column and if it matches with the string that is stored in an array or list the condition is update the status column in the db.

Note: My code is reading from text file and writing to the db but when on comparison it doesnt works

```
      if(textFileStrings.equals(dbtext))
         pstmt.setInt(status,0);
         prepareStatement.updateQuery();
```

Comment: What database are you using? What language? What platform?

Answer (score 1):

try adding brackets, thus:

```
  if(textFileStrings.equals(dbtext)) {
     pstmt.setInt(status,0);
     prepareStatement.updateQuery(); }
```

Comment: i tried enclosing with brackets but still no response am using mysql and java whether it can be done like from db with xl's